# rosserial w/ Arduino Leonardo

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the **rosserial_arduino** package with an Arduino *Leonardo* but I keep getting the error:

> [ERROR] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino

whenever I try to run the *serial_node.py* from the rosserial package...

Can anybody please helpe me?!
Thanks in advance ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125921/rosserial-w/-arduino-leonardo/) by [rflmota](https://answers.ros.org/users/9156/rflmota/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-04**:
So, what about the version mismatch in the error message? What code is on the arduino and what are you running on the ROS machine? The actual workspace might be relevant (i.e. one built from source, one from system)

**Comment by [rflmota](https://answers.ros.org/users/9156/rflmota/) on 2014-02-04**:
I'm using the rosserial version pulled directly from the repository at [rosserial @ GitHub](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial) and I'm using the Hydro distribution for ROS. About the Arduino code, I'm compiling the source code against the generated compiled ros_lib libraries generated by the command:

> rosrun rosserial_arduino serial_node.py ~/sketchbook/libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use some 32U4-based PCBs for test fixtures, prototypes, etc. Here's an example project which builds and downloads an example rosserial firmware to a Leonardo board:

https://github.com/mikepurvis/rosserial_leonardo_example

Note that this bypasses the Arduino IDE, assuming that you will use a text editor and catkin_make it from the command line. I also have a more generalized version of this example which I haven't got clearance to release yet—if that's of interest to anyone, let me know and I can move things along with it.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-02-04**:
Very interested!